# I have a basic php script that displays data from a database in a html table i would to add add a button to call a php script and delete a record

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a basic PHP script that views data from a database and displays it on a table. I have a button on the table and I want it to call a PHP script and delete a record from the database when I click it. I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'button' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

The PHP script has some code with SQL query to delete data from the table

```php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM info");
    
    echo "<center>"; 
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Email</th>";
    echo "<th>Cell</th>";
    echo "<th>quantity</th>";
    echo "<th>message</th>";
    echo "<center>";
    
    echo "</tr>";
```

Query database and display data. I want to call a php script when I click the button (see ajax code at the bottom)

```php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['cell'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['message'] . "<button type="button">delete</button></td>";
    
    
    }
    
    
    $conn->close();
```

The AJAX to handle button click

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
    
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'delete.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $("p").text(data);
    
                    }
                });
       });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `echo "<td>" . $row['message'] . "<button type="button">` - this is a syntax error. If you want to use double quotes inside a double quoted string, you need to escape them. Change `type="button"` to either `type=\"button\"` or even easier `type='button'` (using different types of quotes inside the string when possible). You can read more about strings [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: thanx using single quotes solved the problem.